# A fatal error has been detected libio_micrometer_shaded_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_64

Tags: java, netty, datadog, micrometer

My app stops and become broken on the line Metrics.addRegistry(new StatsdMeterRegistry(configs, clock)

**Environment**

- Micrometer version 1.8.2
- Micrometer registry DataDog
- Docker
- Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz, 4 cores, 1G, Alpine Linux v3.14
- JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.11+9) (build 11.0.11+9-alpine-r0)
- Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.11+9-alpine-r0, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, serial gc, linux-amd64)

I guess some native libs are missing. Please help me how to fix the issue.

**Part of the logs:**

> Stack: [0x00007f310b6ef000,0x00007f310b7efad8], sp=0x00007f310b7ea468,
> free space=1005k Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled
> Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) C
> 0x0000000000003fd6 C
> [libio_micrometer_shaded_netty_transport_native_epoll_x86_641883406040202622072.so+0xbd07]
> netty_jni_util_JNI_OnLoad+0x67 C [libjava.so+0xfc7a]
> Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_00024NativeLibrary_load0+0xba j
> java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z+0
> java.base@11.0.11 j java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load()Z+53
> java.base@11.0.11 j
> java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z+216
> java.base@11.0.11 j
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+46
> java.base@11.0.11 j
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+70
> java.base@11.0.11 j
> java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
> java.base@11.0.11 j java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
> java.base@11.0.11 j
> io.micrometer.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+5
> v ~StubRoutines::call_stub V [libjvm.so+0x817ee3]

[errors full trace can be found here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3177)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated micrometer version to 1.9.0 and netty-all version to 4.1.77 - and it solved the problem! All thanks to Shakuzen!

[full details can be found there](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/3177#issuecomment-1127110695)